# Maps and my own Methods

Tags: java

I was hoping to use the Map to access my methods, but I am unable to access them if they have parameters like this:

```
public static void cmdCheck(String cmd, Stack<String> input) throws Exception{

    cmd=cmd.substring(1,cmd.length());

    Map<String, Method> cmdMap = new HashMap<String, Method>();

    cmdMap.put("login", CommandDirectory.class.getMethod("subCmdCheck"));

    if(cmdMap.containsKey(cmd)){
        cmdMap.get(cmd).invoke(input.pop(), input);
    }else{
        System.out.println("UNKOWN COMMAND");
    }
    System.out.println("Done With Cmd Check");
}

public static Method subCmdCheck(String subCmd, Stack<String> input) throws Exception{
    if(subCmd.indexOf("-")==0){
        System.out.println("WORKING");
    }else{
        System.out.println("MISSING ESSENTIAL INFO, CORRECT USAGE:");
        System.out.println("    .login //Incomplete");
        System.out.println();
    }
    return null;
}
```

How do I access these parameters?

Comment: What do you expect to happen ? Your method signature does not accepts any arguments

Comment: Show what you have tried to pass parameters, then we can see what the problem is with that.

Comment: If you want to pass parameters, you might want to declare methods that actually take parameters.

Comment: You might want to look at the docs on this one https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
cmdMap.get(cmd).invoke(input.pop(), input);
```

with this one:

```
cmdMap.get(cmd).invoke(null, input.pop(), input);
```

The first argument is the instance you're invoking the method on; in case of a static method, you can pass `null`. 
You cannot omit it though, because now the first argument is of the wrong type (`String` instead of the class that your methods are in) and the number of arguments is incorrect.